# How to refer to a chart's app version in another chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I installed a helm chart on K8S cluster and I am able to list it

**Chart - I**

```
root:~# helm list
NAME       NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION
chart1     default         1               2023-07-12 10:02:53.002761513 +0000 UTC deployed        chart1-8.5.5    8.5.5
```

Now, on **Chart-II** I need to implement some functionality based on the "APP_VERSION" of "Chart-I"

**Example code for Chart-II**

```
{{- if .chart1.AppVersion "> 8.0" -}}
    Do something
{{- else }}
    Do something else
{{- end }}
```

Is there a way to implement the functionality mentioned above in helm charts when both charts are independent to each other ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any functionality in Helm that can look at other releases that may or may not be installed in the cluster.  The only thing that can do dynamic queries into the cluster at all is the `lookup` function, and that doesn't have any way to decode the data Helm stores in a Secret objects.

The best you can do here is to make the other chart's version a parameter, and then you can test against `.Values.chart1version` the same way you would any other configurable Helm value.

(Also consider what you might need to do if the other chart is installed multiple times in the cluster, maybe with different versions; and consider what would happen if the other chart is upgraded or deleted; and if your chart logic is complex enough that testing it seems prudent, whether `helm template` would work in this scenario.  I'd tend to avoid charts that behave differently depending on what is already installed.)

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  Is there any better to handle this scenario programmatically or through some other means ?

Comment: Beyond an explicit Helm value, the only other thing that comes to mind is if the thing you're depending on supplies a Kubernetes custom resource definition (CRD), in which case you could use `.APIVersions` to see what's installed.